# SQL Query Syntax gives ERROR 000358: Invalid expression?

Tags: arcpy, sql, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I'm writing a script that will cycle through a shapefile of building footprints for an entire state, create a folder for the individual counties in that state, and then intersect the building footprints file with a county polygon stored.

Because I'm working with multiple states and hundreds of counties, I've created two variables that will take the state and county names of the current iteration- I keep running into an issue when it comes to writing a query that uses those variables.  My goal is to create the following query:

```
"ST_NAME = 'Colorado' AND "POLYGON_NM" = 'Weld'
```

I'm not familiar with writing sql queries in arcpy and the syntax is throwing me.  Here's what I currently have as my query:

```
dictionary = set(zip(statenames, countynames))
for item in dictionary:
    try:
        stname = str(item[0])
        coname = str(item[1].replace(r' ', '_'))
    except:
        stname = str(item[0])
        coname = str(item[1])
    if stname == 'Colorado':
        coco = arcpy.CreateFolder_management((basefile + '/Colorado/Counties'), coname)
        query = '"ST_NAME" =' + "'" + stname + "'" + " AND" + '"POLYGON_NM" =' + "'" + coname + "'"
        fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(counties, 'in_memory/counties_lyr')
        coselect = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fl, '', query)
        fc = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(str(coselect), 'in_memory', coname)
        arcpy.Intersect_analysis([Colorado, fc], (str(coco) + '/' + coname))
```

I keep getting the following error for the Make Feature Layer tool:

```
ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
```

In the past I used a different syntax, but it only produced empty shapefiles, if no errors:

```
query = "ST_NAME" = ('"' + stname + '"') AND "POLYGON_NM" = ('"' + coname + '"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AddFieldDelimiter](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) and three double quotes to get a valid expression:

> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class' #Or a feature layer, table etc.
query = """{0} = '{1}' AND {2} = '{3}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, 'ST_NAME'), stname, arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, 'POLYGON_NM'), coname)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in

```
query = '"ST_NAME" =' + "'" + stname + "'" + " AND" + '"POLYGON_NM" =' + "'" + coname + "'"
```

you are missing a space after `AND` --> `... + " AND " + ...`, so the expression is invalid.

In your other expression, you are using double quotes around `stname` and `coname`, which means they are field name. The expression would be looking for the field Colorado, which doesn't exist.

```
query = "ST_NAME" = ('"' + stname + '"') AND "POLYGON_NM" = ('"' + coname + '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string math makes these sort of errors common. If you instead use `String.format()` syntax, even datatype errors become clear:

```
>>> stname = "foo"
>>> coname = "bar"
>>> query = "\"ST_NAME\" = '{:s}' AND \"POLYGON_NM\" = '{:s}'".format(stname,coname)
>>> print query
"ST_NAME" = 'foo' AND "POLYGON_NM" = 'bar'
```